# MS Access 2013 append(+ sign) option gives error

Tags: microsoft-access

I deleted the relationships,saved the database and opened it again after 15 min and this mysterious append option appears and when clicked this error occurs in employee data and payment table
ERROR

> This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables. (Error 3071)

[DATABASE DOWNLOAD](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1011921E4B430E67%21258)

Comment: Hello! What have you tried already in attempts to get it working? Exactly what steps would we take to reproduce your problem?  I'm not sure shat you mean by "mysterious append option", or where I would find it to click it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: This error occurs when data types of relationships made between fields do not match and when you click append sign in customer data table it gives the error (Error 3071)

which is due to the unmatched datatypes of both fields in diffrent tables.